# Is there any way to push back a vector into a vector? c++

Tags: c++, vector, 2d

For example if I had one or more 2D vectors and I just want to store them in a data base for example.

```
 vector<vector<double>> one2DVector;
 vector<vector<double>> two2DVector;

 //Obviously can't do that but this is what I want to do
 vector<vector> dataBase;

 dataBase.push_back(one2DVector);
 dataBase.push_back(one2DVector);
```

Comment: Polite is good. But do you think someone finding this question ten years from now will care that you had to eat before checking on the replies? :)

Comment: I just feel bad if I don't answer. I'm not trying to ignore people on here when they are helping me.

Comment: @RogerDahl I'm not sure if someone reading the question ten minutes from now will care about whether the OP had to eat before checking replies :P

Comment: @Claud25 I wouldn't worry about these comments too much... joking around lightens the mood

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare it like this:

```
vector<vector<vector<double>>> dataBase;
```

Note that if you using C++98 and not C++11, you need to put spaces between the `>` brackets.

Answer (score 3):

```
vector< vector< vector <double> > > database;
vector<vector<double>> one2DVector;
vector<vector<double>> two2DVector;
...
//insert elements into two-dimension arrays.
...
database.push_back(one2DVector);
database.push_back(two2DVector);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try making your dataBase a

```
vector< vector< vector <double> > >
```

instead of a `vector<vector>` (whatever that is).

Typedefs might help make this a bit more readable

```
typedef vector<vector<double> > vec_2D;

vec_2D one2DVector;
vec_2D two2DVector;

vector<vec_2D> dataBase;
```

Keep in mind that this `dataBase` will hold *copies* of the 2D vectors, which I'm guessing is not really what you want (but maybe it is).  You might want to consider having your database be a container of pointers or container-appropriate smart pointers (like `shared_ptr`).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want `dataBase` to be a vector of 2d vectors. If this is the case then you have to define it like so

`vector<vector<vector<double> > > dataBase;`

Answer (score 0):

```
 vector<vector<double>> one2DVector;
 vector<vector<double>> two2DVector;

 //Obviously can't do that but this is what I want to do
 vector<vector<vector<double> > > dataBase; //HERES THE EDIT

 dataBase.push_back(one2DVector);
 dataBase.push_back(one2DVector);
```

IT should work fine

however if what you want to do is concatenate the vector then you can do.

```
vector<vector<double>>  database(one2DVector);
database.insert(database.end(), two2DVector.begin(), two2DVector.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a vector of `vector<double>` but you're trying to push `vector<vector>`.